# Will embedding icons to CSS increase the swf size?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

If I embed icons in the CSS file and refer to the style name in action script code, is that a good practice? Will that increase the swf size?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Gurjaspal

Answer (score 1):

Yes, whatever way you choose, the font face will be embedded inside the SWF file.

Two ways to limit file size when using embedded fonts are :

- Include only the needed character range. [See this page for more information](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e04.html).
- You can embed fonts in the main application and reference them in other parts of the application that are loaded later on (modules or their stylesheets)

Answer (score 0):

Yes... Embed away.  Flex has many built in compression algorithms that do a fantastic job of reducing file size.  I've tried to optimize this process myself when building for web delivery and ultimately I could not get the file any smaller than flex could embedding the assets natively.

EDIT:

My assumption on adding this second answer is you were asking about icons (imagery) and not fonts.

Comment: did this answer your question?  Going through and checking answers to see how you faired?